# Is there a faster way to getValues from a google spreadsheet than the getValues() function with google app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am creating some scripts using Google Apps Script to help with some of my work on a Google Spreadsheet that has thousands of rows.

For the data - I need to select a whole column, do some calculations on it then add it to another spreadsheet. The problem is that each call to the `getValues()` function executes extremely slowly. It sometimes takes almost 15 seconds to finish the script.

Is there a faster way to get the values from a column using Google Apps Script?

Comment: I think that in your situation, when you provide a sample Spreadsheet and your current script for replicating your issue, it will help users think of the issue and solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: As you tagged, sheets api is usually faster. See Learn more >benchmarks in [tag:google-apps-script] page.

Comment: It's difficult to help you in this case, you should provide a sample code. In my opinion I don't think every call to getValues takes 15 seconds. Try to make one unique call instead of within a loop. This could reduce the execution time drastically.